# How to convert CGPoint in NSValue in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cgpoint, nsvalue

As my question title says how can I convert `CGPoint` into `NSValues` so I can store then Into array In **swift**.

In objective-C we can do it like this:

```
  // CGPoint converted to NSValue
     CGPoint point = CGPointMake(9, 9);
     NSValue *pointObj = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];
```

But can anybody tell me that how can I do this in swift?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Good question :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
let point = CGPointMake(9, 9)
var pointObj = NSValue(CGPoint: point)
```

Comment: idk why there is no popup for this c-tor

Answer (score 12):

Exactly as you'd imagine:

```
let point = CGPoint(x: 9.0, y: 9.0)
let pointObj = NSValue(CGPoint: point)
let newPoint = pointObj.CGPointValue()
```

Answer (score 7):

If you aren't planning on using the array in Objective-C, and can keep it as a Swift Array, then you don't need to turn the point into an NSValue, you can just add the point to the array directly:

```
let point1 = CGPoint(x: 9.0, y: 9.0)
let point2 = CGPoint(x: 10.0, y: 10.0)

let pointArray = [point1, point2] // pointArray is inferred to be of type [CGPoint]

let valuesArray = pointsArray as [NSValue]
```

Comment: But if that was the case, you would be using NSPoint, not CGPoint. It's obvious it's for interop, so your answer is irrelevant for the question.

Answer (score 1):

swift 3

```
let pointObj =  NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x:9, y:9))
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsvalue/1624531-init

Comment: Ok. A few things. pointObj is an odd name for a NSValue. The .init is not required. The parameter you are passing in is a CGSize not a CGPoint. This makes the name even more odd.

Comment: Using .init is wrong/discouraged in Swift in general.

Comment: thx. the ``pointObj`` was regarded to the accepted answer to be consistent for better reading. I am going to edit that.

Comment: This is very strange but it does not exist in macOS, it is simply 'point'

Answer (score 1):

swift 4

```
let point = NSValue.init(cgPoint: mask.position)
```