# How do I store CGPoint in a Dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift

So I am trying to store some info in my `NSDictionary` and I need to store a `CGPoint` value. I am trying something like this:

```
var dict = ["name" : "john", "age" : 20, "coords": (5, 10)]
```

Doesn't work unfortunately. How do I store it (so I can call it `dict["coords"]`)?

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251678/how-to-convert-cgpoint-in-nsvalue-in-swift

Comment: Why was this question marked as duplicate? The linked question looks different a little, and Mehdi's answer is better than the linked answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `coords` is not declared. I guess you meant `"coords"`.

Comment: Forgot the parenthesis in my question, but I do have them in my code ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this :

```
var dict:[String:Any] = ["name" : "john", "age" : 20, "coords": (5, 10)]

println(dict["coords"])
```

Comment: Now I have problems with downcasting from Any lol.

Comment: Use `CGPointMake(5, 10)` instead of `(5, 10)` so you can cast the value as `CGPoint`.